# Make SLIME aware of file extensions other than ".lisp"

Tags: slime

I'm a happy user of Emacs and SLIME.

It looks like SLIME is aware of only files with the extension ".lisp" and not others such as ".cl" or ".asd"

How can I make SLIME aware of and work with different file extensions? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "aware of"?

Comment: When I start out with an *.asd file on SLIME, the C-c C-c just doesn't work though *.asd is a proper lisp file. So I had to change the extension to .lisp and I think that's redundant work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.cl\\'" . slime-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.asd\\'" . slime-mode))
```

to your init/config file. Then files with those extensions will use `slime-mode` by default. This pattern of `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.EXTENSION\\'" . MODE))` is a good way to have files with the extension **EXTENSION** open in the mode **MODE**. Just be careful that you have the `"\\.EXTENSION\\'"` part, which is a regular expression, formatted correctly (with slashes and quotes in the right places), or you will will not get the results you want.

Comment: It was looking likely to work but it didn't. I added those lines to my CMUCL init script at ~/.cmucl-init.lisp and then it said : Error in KERNEL:%COERCE-TO-FUNCTION:  the function ADD-TO-LIST is undefined. I deleted them from cmucl-init and added to ~/.emacs, but this time it made no difference, .cl files are still not evaluated.

Comment: It definitely needs to be added to your .emacs and not the other init script you mention. Also, it probably should be added after slime is loaded

Comment: @Ömer You'll want to use `lisp-mode` instead of `slime-mode`.